# .htaccess redirect all extension except css and javascript

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, web-applications

I have a **.htaccess** file that redirect any extension to a non-extension url and displays the *requestedfilename + .php*. It works great with the **(.*)** part of the conditions.

When I type *domain.com/file.html* or *domain.com/file.xml* it displays the *file.php* and the url looks like *domain.com/file*.

I just would like to know how to exculde extensions like .js and .css from the expression. I don't want to redirect them to any other php file.

I tried things like: **(.*!.(js|css))** instead of **(.*)** but I can't find a working solution...

The current code is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#
# to display the name.php file for any requested extension (.*)
#
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(.*) $1\.php

#
# to hide all type of extensions (.*) of urls
#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.(.*)\sHTTP/.+
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php $1 [R=301,L]

#
# no extension url to php
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your version of Apache supports it, you may be able to use "negative lookahead" and write the first RewriteRule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(?!js|css)([^.]*)$ $1\.php
```

The `[^.]`part makes sure the `(.*)\.` matches everything until the last `.`, "positioning" the negative lookahead at the right spot.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea of redirect, is to forward something, when it's not there, so redirect will work only, if the requested url is not present. If you have a `http://mysite.com/js/script.js` file, it will always open that file as normal one.

So in your case, you don't need a specific redirect for css and js files, if they are actually there.

What you might need to do, is to point the **full** path of those files. In example:

- http://mysite.com/js/script.js ( works )
- /js/script.js ( works )
- js/script.js ( will fail if you are under a different redirected directory then root )

etc...

Comment: Well, if you want to, you can of course force a redirect even if the file or directory exists. That's what `-d` and `-f` are for.

Comment: Yeah, I was just commenting on the "it will always open that file as normal one" which isn't the case.