# Can't access assets on public after setting document root to /public

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I've just recently started using Laravel on a new project and I hit a problem.

So, I think I've set up everything well for a new project and began working on it. Everything is fine on my local machine (Windows, running WAMP) and I've set it up on a personal VPS (Ubuntu, running NGINX), which is also working fine. Now, my employer is using Shared Hosting and the access is sadly very limited. I have ftp access and he can access some stuff on a cPanel. I've tried deploying to the server directly from my local project with PhpStorm. It seemed ok, only bump was that it was directing to a file listing, but when accessing serverlink/public it seemed ok. I've asked my employer to change the document root to /public and everything went downhill, as I now can't access my assets (css/images) which are on /public. The generated links are what they're supposed to be eg: serverlink/css/mycss.css but the file returns a 404 which is rather odd.

Here's my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

On my views I'm referencing the assets using blade, like so:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/button.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

What I get when trying to access the files directly in the browser is

"Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
1/1 NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:"

Can anyone help me out? Going nuts over this, especially as it works fine on my vps! Will I need to forsake Laravel 5 because of the hosting restrictions or can I get around them?

Cheers,
Tiago C.

Comment: What does `asset('css/button.css')` render? What `url()` returns?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect all extension except css and javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202316/htaccess-redirect-all-extension-except-css-and-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line index.php

```
 $app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

And change public directory to main directory.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a problem with an .htaccess on the root directory that required authentication. Somehow, I guess when the root folder was set to public that other .htaccess was blocking access to files (since the auth was not asked). I since edited it out and changed my .htaccess (inside public) to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Which also removed the need for "index.php/" or similiar on my routes.

Cheers!